# How to cut the nth line of file by using the value of the nth line from another file?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, cut

i tried to cut the first line of file A with the value in the first line of file B, the 2nd line of file A with the value of in the 2nd line of file B and so on ...

I tried this code:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  cut -c $line- file.A
done < file.B >out.txt
```

the issue is, that bash cut all lines from file A with the value of the first line, followed by cutting all line from file A with the 2nd value of the file B...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read both files line by line. This can be done with an additional file descriptor

```
while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -ru3 b; do
  cut -c "$a"- <<< "$b"
done < file.A 3< file.B > out.txt
```

Here you can also use bash built-ins instead of `cut` to make the script run a bit faster:

```
while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -ru3 b; do
  printf %s\\n "${b:a-1}"
done < file.A 3< file.B > out.txt
```

Both commands from above assume 1-base indices as the code in your question did too. If you are using 0-based indices, change the loop body to

```
cut -c "$((a+1))"- <<< "$b"
```

or

```
printf %s\\n "${b:a}"
```

Comment: Thx for your advise!
The 2nd command work very well!. The first one didn't run, i got this error: "cut: [-cf] list: values may not include zero" thousand of times ...

Comment: Glad I could help. You can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this (or any other answer) to say thanks (the author gets points) and close your question. Regarding the error: Do you get the error too when using the script from your question? If so, then it is an off-by-one error: You assumed the first character had the index 0, but `cut` indexes them starting from 1. I added variants for 0-based indexing.

Comment: Thanks again! ;) Everything works now! I accepted ur answer, but i couldn't vote for you, because i am new and got 0 reputation ...

Comment: Hey, is there anyway to read every line in file A and cut every 4th line in file B with the value of file A?

Comment: Yes, I suppose, even though I didn't understand what exactly you want. Please open a new question in which you include a minimal example (input and expected output).